# Automatic right justify in table - multiple choice question

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

My code part

```
\newcommand{\iib}[5]{
\begin{center}
\begin{tabu} to 0.42\textwidth {@{}|X[l]@{}|X[l]|}
\textbf{A)} #1 & \textbf{B)} #2\\
\textbf{C)} #3 & \textbf{D)} #4\\
\multicolumn{2}{@{}|c|}{\textbf{E)} #5}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}}
```

and output,

[image]

But that I want,

[image]

Is this possible automatic for all answers? That is, **B)** and **D)** choices will (right) slide according to word. But, considering long word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can try the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\multiplechoices}[5]{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|l|}
    \textbf{A)} #1 & \textbf{B)} #2 \\
    \textbf{C)} #3 & \textbf{D)} #4 \\
   \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{\centering\textbf{E)} #5}
  \end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Is this question wrong?

  \multiplechoices{THE END}{END}{GAME OVER}{FINISH}{STOP}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The last column is set using `l`, meaning the first `X`-column will stretch up to it, yet the entire table will fill the `\linewidth`. The last row is centered based on a fixed-width `p`-column that also fits `\linewidth`.

Comment: @ Werner, perfect working in all choices.