# Place circuit figures side by side in tabularx environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate, tabularx, input

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\newcommand{\OOO}[4]{%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{}l@{}}
\textbf{A)} #1 & \textbf{B)} #2 \\
\textbf{C)} #3 & \textbf{D)} #4 \\
\end{tabularx}}

{\item  Convert the current source into an equivalent voltage source\\
\OOO{\input{./ABC/SZ-1a.tex}}
{\input{./ABC/SZ-1b.tex}}
{\input{./ABC/SZ-1c.tex}}
{\input{./ABC/SZ-1d.tex}}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

Also

```
{\item Convert the current source into an equivalent voltage source...\\
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{A)} & \textbf{B)}\\
\input{./ABC/SZ-1a.tex}&\input{./ABC/SZ-1a.tex}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
\textbf{C)} & \textbf{D)}\\
\input{./ABC/SZ-1c.tex}&\input{./ABC/SZ-1d.tex}
\end{tabular}}
```

And displaying

[image]

Related to: [Automatic right justify in table - multiple choice question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223220/automatic-right-justify-in-table-multiple-choice-question)

How is it shift down? Is there a solve?

Comment: Are you also interested in a solution without `tabularx` which would give an equal width to the cells A, B, C, and D ?

Comment: @HarishKumar, It didn't worked.

Comment: Use this: `\OOO{\input{./ABC/SZ-1a.tex}
{\input{./ABC/SZ-1b.tex}}
{\input{./ABC/SZ-1c.tex}}
{\input{./ABC/SZ-1d.tex}}}`

Comment: You have an extra brace at the end of `\OOO{\input{./ABC/SZ-1a.tex}`.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm, update my question.

Comment: @HarishKumar, unfortunatelly it didn't worked, too.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood it correctly, there is no special requirement for a `tabularx` or `tabular` solution.

The macro `\OOO` could be made with help of four minipages. I provide another way using `tcolorbox` and its `raster` library to set up the four parts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\newcommand{\OOO}[4]{%
\begin{tcbitemize}[blanker,fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,
    raster valign=top,raster row skip=2mm,raster column skip=4mm]
  \tcbitem[title=A)] #1
  \tcbitem[title=B)] #2
  \tcbitem[title=C)] #3
  \tcbitem[title=D)] #4
\end{tcbitemize}}

\item Convert the current source into an equivalent voltage source
  \OOO{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
      {\small\lipsum[2]}
      {\small\lipsum[3]}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The code above produces top align parts or cells. The following variation produces center aligned cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\newcommand{\OOO}[4]{%
\begin{tcbitemize}[blanker,fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,valign=center,
    raster equal height=rows,
    raster row skip=2mm,raster column skip=4mm]
  \tcbitem[title=A)] #1
  \tcbitem[title=B)] #2
  \tcbitem[title=C)] #3
  \tcbitem[title=D)] #4
\end{tcbitemize}}

\item Convert the current source into an equivalent voltage source
  \OOO{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
      {\small\lipsum[2]}
      {\small\lipsum[3]}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, there comes another variation which frames the four parts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,raster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\newcommand{\OOO}[4]{%
\begin{tcbitemize}[enhanced,size=small,sharp corners,colback=white,
    colframe=black!20,colbacktitle=blue!10,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=black,valign=center,
    raster equal height=rows,raster row skip=1mm,raster column skip=1mm]
  \tcbitem[title=A)] #1
  \tcbitem[title=B)] #2
  \tcbitem[title=C)] #3
  \tcbitem[title=D)] #4
\end{tcbitemize}}

\item Convert the current source into an equivalent voltage source
  \OOO{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
      {\small\lipsum[2]}
      {\small\lipsum[3]}
      {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]